# Partition in QuickSort using Linked List

Tags: sorting

I was implementing partition function in quicksort using linked list but I am confused whether to swap node data only or the whole node.

Comment: Instead of swapping nodes, you could recursively split the list into 3 lists, nodes < pivot, nodes == pivot, nodes >pivot, then recurse on the lists with nodes != pivot. To avoid scanning, you could choose the first node of a list as the pivot, although this will be worst case on already sorted data.

Comment: I am welcoming another approach. Actually, I was asked this question in interview that if I need to use this approach then should I swap the whole node or only that data and why?

Comment: The choice should be swapping node data versus swapping node linkage. Ignoring cache locality issues, then the issue is which is larger, the size of the data or the size of the links. A [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) would be faster than quick sort for a linked list, but it would be faster still to generate an array of pointers (or references) to the nodes, and use an array based sort. Cache locality issues would depend on where the nodes are located in memory.